# Recovering from PostgreSQL connection closing after JPA error

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Sometimes my application tries to delete data that have reference to another data and this launch a "data integrity violation", which is expected.

> ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Entrada em lote 0 delete from item_tabela_protese where id='2' foi abortada. Chame getNextException para ver a causa.
>
> ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ERROR: update or delete on table "item_tabela_protese" violates foreign key constraint "fk_item_tabela_protese" on table "pedido_protese"
>         Detalhe: Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "pedido_protese".

After this error above I can't do anything in application, i got a "Postgres connection closed".

> ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - This connection has been closed.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

After a forced rollback, you must close your session and obtain a new one. Generally you only have to `rollback` the transaction and open a new transaction, but it looks like Hibernate might be closing the connection when it sees an error on it. It's hard to be sure without more log detail.

First try rolling back the transaction and obtaining a new Hibernate session.

You can't just keep using a session in the same transaction after a failure. The transaction is in an invalid state where all statements except `ROLLBACK` will produce an error.

If you wish to deal with that you *might* be able to use `SAVEPOINT`s and `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` (at a performance cost), but it's likely Hibernate's caching won't deal well with that.